# trouble using c# variables from SQL with Google Graphs

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

If you scroll down a bit to view the code of ["A Simple Example"](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart) you will see

```
var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      vAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
    };
```

On my aspx page I have the following code in order to use a variable in place of the hard coded title.

```
var options = {
            title: '<%=strMeasure%>',
            vAxis: { title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: { color: 'red' } }
        };
```

I also have placed this variable in in the head section by itself as well as binding the value to a label's text attribute and they both display.

here is my code behind:

```
protected string strQualityID, strSites, strServiceLine, strMeasure;
    protected int CompanyAvg, KYStateAvg, NationalAvg;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            strQualityID = Request.QueryString["num"];
            using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT QT.Sites [Sites], QTSL.ServiceLine [ServiceLine],  QTM.Measure [Measure], QTM.CompanyAvg [CompanyAvg], QTM.KYStateAvg [KYStateAvg], QTM.NationalAvg [NationalAvg]
                                                    FROM [quality_Measures] QTM
                                                    Inner JOIN [quality_ServiceLines] QTSL
                                                    Left Join [quality_Sites] QT
                                                    ON QTSL.[SiteID] = QT.[num]
                                                    ON QTM.[ServiceLineID] = QTSL.[num]", conn1);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", strQualityID);
                conn1.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader1.Read())
                    {
                        strSites = reader1.GetString(0);
                        strServiceLine = reader1.GetString(1);
                        strMeasure = reader1.GetString(2);
                        CompanyAvg = reader1.GetInt32(3);
                        KYStateAvg = reader1.GetInt32(4);
                        NationalAvg = reader1.GetInt32(5);
                    }
                }                    
            }


            lblRow.Text = strQualityID;
            lblSites.Text = strSites;
            lblServiceLine.Text = strServiceLine;
            lblMeasure.Text = strMeasure;
            lblCompany.Text = Convert.ToString(CompanyAvg);
            lblState.Text = Convert.ToString(KYStateAvg);
            lblNational.Text = Convert.ToString(NationalAvg);
        }
    }
```

When I run the application the graph is not there, but if I add:

```
strMeasure = "This is a test";
```

Then the graph displays with the new string value of `strMeasure`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this title: title: '<%=strMeasure%>' to title: 'title text'.  ?

Answer (score 0):

I added this to resolve the issue

```
strMeasure = reader1.GetString(2);
string MyStrMeasure = strMeasure.Trim();
```